# Regular expression - matching inside a string

Tags: regex, oracle

I have been trying to find a regular expression for matching just numbers in the following expression but I need certain group.

For example:

**Vdsl 1.10.4**

How it's possible to match **10**

Also I need an expression for matching **4**

P.S I'm using as Regex flavour Oracle SQL function regex_substr()

Thanks

---

Edit:

I think I found a workaround:

- with REGEXP_SUBSTR() you can match it with dots: '.10.' Afterwards with REGEXP_REPLACE the number can be extracted.

  REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Vdsl 1.10.4','.\d+.'),
               '.(\d+).',
               '\1')
- and for the last number

  REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Vdsl 1.10.4','.\d+$'),
               '.(\d+)',
               '\1')

Comment: Without dots. Should be 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1116)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT 'Vdsl 1.10.4' AS str
  FROM   DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '\.\d+', 1, 1 ), 2 ) AS FIRST_NUMBER,
       SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR( str, '\.\d+', 1, 2 ), 2 ) AS SECOND_NUMBER
FROM   DATA
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1116/0)**:

```
| FIRST_NUMBER | SECOND_NUMBER |
|--------------|---------------|
|           10 |             4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 10 is between 2 dot you can dimply use `\.(\d+)\.` and for 4 since its after one dot and comes at end you can use `\.(\d+)$`.

You can use a proper function and extract the first group which is your number. if you can't or don't want to get the group you can use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)
```

Read more about basic regex http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Yes, but how I am supposed to remove the leading and the trail points?

Comment: @lindusilois I'm not familiar with Oracle.you can try one of this ways or search for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very very simple RegEx:

```
(?=\.([0-9]+))
```

For the one at the end:

```
([0-9]+)$
```

Comment: lookbehind is not supported in Oracle SQL

Comment: @lindusilois is look-**ahaed** supported?

Comment: @lindusilois try: `\.([0-9]+)\.`

Comment: this includes the dots but I don't want them

Comment: @lindusilois okay, try: `[0-9]{2}`

Comment: Well...this might work but for instance I can have just one digit instead of 2 into that portion of string

Comment: @lindusilois is there not a function to extract a capturing group?

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have managed to use another function for this. Brainstorming is useful as you have comrades willing to help you.